# Ubuntu install fail

Tags: system-installation

(Errno 2 No Such file or directory zpool)
I always got this Error when install i download iSO two time try on both DVD and USB  Always got this Error but Ubuntu Desktop work (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS)

Comment: Did the downloaded iso have the right md5/sha hash? And the DVD/USB?

Comment: How can i check that i just download from Ubuntu Website

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu

Comment: I Try it its ok

Comment: Then it should work... Are you saying the USB boots & runs (in try/demo/live mode) ok? Something else must be wrong, but without more info I don't know what it could be. Were you trying to install Ubuntu somewhere (and where) when the error happens? What's the full error, what program or window says it,  and then what happens?

Answer (score 0):

As i missing the needed reputation and therefor cannot comment on the initial question...
Here is some additional input to this problem.

Today, i encountered the same error message during a Ubuntu Server 18.04.1.0-LTS install from an USB stick filled with "ubuntu-18.04.1.0-live-server-amd64.iso".

First thing i did was checking the SHA256 of the downloaded ISO; it was downloaded correctly!

After booting the USB drive i did the a regular install.

1. English Language
2. German Keyboard Layout
3. Install Ubuntu
4. Static IPv4 config (no IPv6)
5. No Proxy
6. Country based Mirror
7. Install using "An Entire Disk"
8. Confirm Partitioning
9. First user setup

The Error appears during the setup of the first user when the disk gets formatted in background task.

[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub1Yx.png)

[Full error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c3Yi.png)

To me it looks like the setup runtime is missing the zpool executable.

Funny thing; this shall be the fresh install of my ZFS based NAS; so i thought the error comes at the moment the setup trys to import my existing ZFS-Pool
My first action was to detach all the ZFS storage HDDs leaving only the boot device connected, with no luck; the error persits.

I tried as well to leave DHCP Address (instead of the static IPv4) config and keep the default Ubuntu Mirror instead the local country mirror; same, no luck!

After receiving the error i entered the console, manually installed the zfsutils-linux package and retried the mentioned "zpool list -H -o name" command which worked fine [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKHWy.png)